# JQuery selective selection

Tags: jquery, css, selection

I have some dynamic menu. Once when someone click a link into the menu i want to highlight this clicked menu.

```
$("#my_menu > li").click(function(){
   var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
   $("#" + clickedId).css("font-weight", "bold");
   $("#" + clickedId).css("background-color", "#E0E0E0");
   $('#navigation_submenu').show(); //this is not important
});
```

But now i must to revert to the initial state the other menus.
Please someone can help me how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: why not just $(this).css() instead of adding the id string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The better way to do that is using `addClass()` and `removeClass()` this way:

- First in your CSS create a class for the active items:

  ```
  .active {
     font-weight:bold;
     background-color:#E0E0E0;
  }
  ```
- Then with Jquery:

  ```
  $("#my_menu > li").click(function(){
     //Remove previous active item
     $("#my_menu > li").removeClass('active');
     //Add class on clicked element
     $(this).addClass('active')   
  });
  ```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz2bg/)**

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

**CSS**

```
li.active
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#my_menu > li").on("click", function()
{
    $("#my_menu > li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a CSS-class for "active" instead.

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

And you of course need a CSS class specification with your bold and more.

Edit: Oups, I was too slow. Others Have given you almost the same answer.